# Get time difference between two datetime objects as hour, min and sec

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to get the amount of hours, mins and seconds that have passed between two dates using datetime in python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows for the duration to be calculated, and makes the amount of hours, mins and seconds that have passed.

Note this has not been fully tested.
Code can also be found on Github [here](https://gist.github.com/enchant97/ff42bc7736e9b5bad11fdb65b9804b76)

```
from datetime import datetime
def calculate_time_duration(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    """
    Requires two datetime objects,
    returns (hours, minutes, seconds)
    """
    seconds = (end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds()
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds -= minutes * 60
    hours = minutes // 60
    minutes -= hours * 60
    return hours, minutes, seconds
```

Comment: Why would you put the more up to date code off somewhere else?